# Как сравнить универсальный тип T?

Tags: c#, методы, типы-данных

Везде, где я находил ответы, T объявлялся в классе, но у меня он объявляется в методе:

```cs
        public static List<T> Max<T>(this List<T> List, int start = 0, int end = 0)
        {
            if (end == 0) end = List.Count-1;

            T Max = List[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < end; i++)
            {

                if (List[i] > Max) Max = List[i]; //">" невозможно применить к операнду типа "T" и "T"
            }

            return Max;
        }
```

И поэтому прилепить `: where T : IComparable<T>` я не могу (пробовал, никуда не прилепляется). Как поступать в таком случае?

Comment: Первую `:` уберите

Comment: А куда ` where T : IComparable<T>` лепить? Если после методов и скобок, то where уже не подчёркивается, но ошибка (сравнение двух Т) сохраняется

Comment: Ну вы сказали `прилепить : where T : IComparable<T> я не могу`, я вам дал подсказку почему, в методах это задается без `:` в начале, просто `where ...`, а само сравнение там уже должно идти через `CompareTo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static T Max<T>(this List<T> list, int startIndex = 0, int endIndex = -1) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (endIndex == -1)
            endIndex = list.Count - 1;

        T max = list[0];
        for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].CompareTo(max) > 0)
                max = list[i];
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> list = new List<int> { 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 0 };
    int max = list.Max();
    Console.WriteLine(max);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

```
6
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124720/discussion-on-answer-by-aepot-----t).

Comment: Правильнее наверное использовать `Comparer<T>.Default`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JHNlWm.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static T Max<T>(this List<T> List, int start = 0, int end = 0) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if (end == 0) end = List.Count - 1;

    T Max = List[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < end; i++)
    {

        if (List[i].CompareTo(Max) > 0) Max = List[i];
    }

    return Max;
}
```